# String interpolation not printing value of variables, is printing exact string

Tags: ruby

I have a mailer that looks like (`@user` and `@foo` are passed to the containing method):

```
mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Foo is expired', 
    body: 'Your Foo reservation for #{@foo.bar.name} in position #{@foo.position}
    has expired.  Please recreate the reservation if necessary')
```

I'm testing it with some puts, puts mail.body looks like:

```
'Your Foo reservation for #{@foo.bar.name} in position #{@foo.position}
 has expired.  Please recreate the reservation if necessary'
```

Am I just mistaken on how I'm doing interpolation?  Has it something to do with ActionMailer, or outputting text to console?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using `%Q!a string without quote, with string interpolation like this:  #{ruby_variable}!` if you want to use quotes but not escape them (reference: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Alternate_quotes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String interpolation in `ruby` only work with double quotes `""`

Answer (score 3):

For interpolation to work, you need to use double quotes `"` not single quote `'`:

```
> a = 'test'
 => "test" 
> 'Testing #{a}'     # This won't interpolate
 => "Testing \#{a}" 
> "Testing {a}"      # This interpolates               
 => "Testing test"
```